# How to send a property of the current element as as a command parameter in WPF?

Tags: wpf, command, commandparameter

I have a button with a Background color, and I want to send this Background color as the Command Parameter to the Command Binding! How can I do that?

```
<Button Background="Red" Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding this.Background}" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you have to use RelativeSource in the binding...

```
<Button Background="Red" Command="{Binding ChangeColorCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
            Path=Background}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the wanted result!